# Change a textfield into a link with the value of the textfield when it has lost focus, and back again when you click the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a Private Messaging system, and I wanted to make it start with a textbox for the "To" field, then when you click out of it for the first time (it starting as a text box) it turns into a Link such as this:
POC0bob (edit) and when you click the Username, it will take you to their profile in a blank tab, when you click the edit it all goes back to a textbox.

[Link to jsfiddle with what I have so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/fnVNc/954/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.edit').click(function () {
    var dads = $(this).parent().parent();
    var dad = $(this).parent();
    dads.find('label').hide();
    dad.find('editusnm').hide();
    dads.find('input[type="text"]').show().focus();
});

$('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
    var dad = $(this).parent();
    $(this).hide();
    dad.find('label').show();
});
```

});

I sorta stole that code, and edited it from another stackoverflow question, but it didn't help much.

That is kind of the basic idea I have, but I need the textbox and link to change based on the value of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the text and href attribute of the link on focusout by updating the focusout function to this:

```
$('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
  var dad = $(this).parent();
  $(this).hide();
  dad.find('label').show();
  // Get username 
  var username = $(this).val();
  // Set the jQuery object to a variable so we're not getting it twice
  var $usernamelink = $('#username');
  // Set the link text to the text box value
  $usernamelink.text(username);
  // Set the link href incorporating the textbox value
  $usernamelink.attr("href", "/Profile/?user=" + username + "");
});
```

Then add an id to your anchor:

```
<p class="text-info"><a id="username" href="/Profile/?user=[Username]">Username</a></p>
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2sgdx22/

Comment: How dod I get it to update/change the href link as well to add the new username?

Comment: One last question, @calum is there possibly a way to make it so that it only switches if the textbox is not blank? I tried a few things, such as if($(this).length >= 1) and if($(this)){} with no luck.